# How to connect to a Scratch org using jsForce in continuous integration

Tags: salesforcedx

This is a follow up of the question:

[Does SFDX jwt authorization work for scratch orgs as well?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257216/does-sfdx-jwt-authorization-work-for-scratch-orgs-as-well)

We need to obtain a jsForce connection towards the Scratch Org. After we have created, we select the `AuthCode` from `ScratchOrgInfo` and we build the loginUrl from the `ActiveScratchOrg` as so `https://${SignupInstance}.salesforce.com`

```
return new jsforce.Connection({
                instanceUrl: loginUrl,
                clientId: : clientId,
                clientSecret : clientSecret,
                redirectUri: "http://localhost:1717/OauthRedirect",
                accessToken: AuthCode,
                version: '40.0',
              })
```

using the same clientId we use to perform the jwt auth grant on the DevHub, and the matching clientSecret taken from the DevHub Org. We verified that:

- our ScratchOrgInfo field ConnectedAppConsumerKey matches the clientId
- the ConnectedAppCallbackUrl matches the redirectUri in the login

Still, we get

> invalid_grant: authentication failure

What are we missing to get the authentication succeed? Also, if the organization has been created some time ago, we notice that we would instead get

> invalid_grant: expired authorization code.

One additional strategy we tried was to use the sfdx-cli node package to get the result of `force:org:list --json --verbose` and pass the accessToken, and now the error is different:

```
invalid_grant: expired access/refresh token
```

Comment: are you sure **clientSecret** is latest one your passing to it.

Comment: the error message itself saying it's been authentication failure, the same thing i got few days back(while integrating to the Node api's). check with you email you would have latest token key in it , when you update the password. you would get this.  concate it with your password and pass it int   **password**  this is missing from you snippet

Comment: @UmeshBeti concatenating username and password applies only to the resource owner flow, here we are talking about fully automated processes running on continuos integration server