# Cannot authorize a Scratch Org via JWT - invalid_grant - user hasn't approved this consumer

Tags: salesforcedx, oauth2, connected-apps, jwt

I've followed the [docs here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth_jwt_flow.htm#sfdx_dev_auth_jwt_scratch) to create a cert and configured the following;

- OAuth scopes: `api`, `refresh_token`, `offline_access` and `web`
- Permitted users: `Admin approved users are pre-authorized`
- Profiles: All (even though I suspect `System Administrator` should be enough)

I can successfully authenticate to the DevHub with `force:auth:jwt:grant`, but cannot authorize an associated Scratch Org.  I run the following command;

```
sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant \
--clientid 3MVG97quAmFZJfVz.WJ55DLNvbWWJlZL.ag6Zr_Xp4u5TXmwoRKSdXVzB.KrzU1oXwQIkjCxczxHWcQpWBotZ \
--jwtkeyfile /keys/server.key \
--setalias scratchorg \
--username test-3zcz2xcrrsfb@example.com \
--instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com
```

But receive the following error;

```
ERROR running force:auth:jwt:grant:  This org appears to have a problem with its OAuth configuration. Reason: invalid_grant - user hasn't approved this consumer
username: test-3zcz2xcrrsfb@example.com,
clientId: 3MVG97quAmFZJfVz.WJ55DLNvbWWJlZL.ag6Zr_Xp4u5TXmwoRKSdXVzB.KrzU1oXwQIkjCxczxHWcQpWBotZ,
loginUrl: <Not Specified>,
privateKey: /keys/server.key

Try this:
Verify the OAuth configuration for this org. For JWT:
Ensure the private key is correct and the cert associated with the connected app has not expired.
Ensure the following OAuth scopes are configured [api, refresh_token, offline_access]. Ensure the username is assigned to a profile or perm set associated with the connected app.
Ensure the connected app is configured to pre-authorize admins.
```

- [Similar question #1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257216/does-sfdx-jwt-authorization-work-for-scratch-orgs-as-well) - solved by waiting, but my scratch org has been up for 24 hours.
- [Similar question #2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/271420/oauth-throws-invalid-grant-user-hasnt-approved-this-consumer-randomly-for-co) - the following values for `instanceurl` do not solve this; login, test, community
- [Blog post #1](http://www.wadewegner.com/2018/01/jwt-oauth-with-scratch-orgs/) - same as the official docs, still throws error
- [Blog post #2](https://mannharleen.github.io/2020-03-03-salesforce-jwt/) - Step 3 Option 1 mentions setting `Admin approved users are pre-authorized` and enabling profiles, I've already done this
- [Similar question #3](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/31969/oauth-2-0-jwt-bearer-token-flow-giving-a-user-hasnt-approved-this-consumer-erro) - suggests the application needs to be authorized, which I'm guessing it is already, per Blog post #2 above.

How can I authorize my scratch org using JWT?

Comment: Salesforce DX has a refresh token for the scratch org it creates. Is there a reason you need to authenticate to the scratch org with JWT?

Comment: Testing/building a CI pipeline on Developer Edition.  I will pop the 6/day cap if I create a new scratch org every time while building this pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

The fix here for me was to create the Scratch Org *after* I had created the Connected App;

- Scratch Org #1

  - Created before the Connected App was created
  - Cannot authorize at all, even 24 hours later, with JWT
- Scratch Org #2

  - Created after the Connected App was created
  - Failed to authorize with JWT for about 2mins (per docs), but then connected successfully

It's not apparent to me what difference the Scratch Orgs have (ie; neither have reference to the Connected App)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this. The instanceurl value I used is the LoginUrl from the ScratchOrgInfo object queried from the devhub