# Cannot login to the sandbox app using JWT: invalid_grant: user hasn't approved this consumer (400)

Tags: sandbox, jwt, ruby

so I generated and uploaded self-signed certificate, created an app, selected "Admin approved users are pre-authorized", added username role to approved list and wrote following code (using Ruby and Restforce library):

```
Restforce.configure do |config|
  config.username = "username"
  config.client_id = "production_client_id"
  config.client_secret = "production_client_secret"
  config.instance_url ="production_instance_url"
  config.jwt_key = "jwt_key"
  config.api_version = '48.0'
end
```

Then run:

```
Restforce.new.describe
```

It works completely fine! I can connect to the API and have full access.

Then I created sandbox, app has been copied to sandbox too. I replaced username, client_id, client_secret, instance_url with sandbox settings. Run "Restforce.new.describe" again and it shows and error:

```
invalid_grant: user hasn't approved this consumer (400)
```

What I tried:

1) Change from "Admin approved users are pre-authorized" to "All users may self-authorize", login to test instance with user credentials (permissions are displayed) and confirm.

2) Create new app on sandbox from scratch.

3) Change username from "email@example.com.sandboxname" to "email@example.com" (as on production).

None of the above works for me. The error is the still the same (I read 1st hack helped some people but it doesn't work for me).

Comment: Along the lines of this issue having been [flagged](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/300693/cannot-authorize-a-scratch-org-via-jwt-invalid-grant-user-hasnt-approved-th/) [by other users](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/306081/jwt-connectiong-failing-with-connected-app-in-a-different-org), try a non-JWT flow on your new org.

Comment: ...or wait for N hours and try JWT again.

Comment: Waiting for few days already :(